# Working with classes (creating a class efficiently, drawing and updating all instances of the class every frame)

Tags: python, pygame

I've been working on a "bullet hell" game of my own, but I am struggling very much with working with classes (im new to python), below i've enclosed my code(I wouldnt include so much but i dont know howo to go about the problem). At the moment what i've been attempting to
 1. Create different instances of the class
 2. Draw them every frame
 3. Update their position every frame according to the x and y speed

```
import pygame

# Define colors needed

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)

bulletArray = []

BulletSprite = ("Bullet4.png")

pygame.init()

class Bullet:
  def __init__(self, sprite, x, y, xSpeed, ySpeed):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.xSpeed = xSpeed
    self.ySpeed = ySpeed
    bulletArray.append(self)


    def update(self):
      pass

    def draw(screen):
      self.screen = screen
      screen.blit(screen, (x, y))

#Set the width and height of the game screen
size = (700, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("Bullet stuff")

# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False

# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


testBullet = Bullet(BulletSprite, 200, 200, 2, 2)
#Main Program Loop
while not done:
  # --- Main event loop
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      done = True

  # --- Game logic should go here



  print(bulletArray)
  # --- background image.
  screen.fill(WHITE)

  # --- Drawing code should go here


  # --- Updates the screen every frame with whats been drawn
  pygame.display.flip()

  # --- Limit to 60 frames per second
  clock.tick(60)

# Close the window and quit.
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Your question seems a bit unclear to me. Are you asking if there's something specifically broken in your code, or are you perhaps asking other people to write rest of the code for you or what?

Comment: Ah forgive me, i wasnt totally sure how to go about asking it.
essentially all i was wanting was to create a class for the bullets, update them each frame using their x and y speeds, then draw them each frame

I tried to set up classes on my own using guides and whatnot found online but i simply do not know how to go about this

Comment: While some kind spirit may answer your question, I believe better approach would be to split those problems to small, verifiable problems, attempt to solve them and then ask explicit questions about each individual problem.

Comment: alright, il give it another go soon, thanks for your time ^^

Answer (score 0):

Much of the this mechanism is already handled automatically if you use the PyGame [Sprite Class](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html).

A PyGame sprite is essentially made of:

- An Image to draw to represent the object
- A rectangle around the object to remember the location and check for collisions
- An `update()` function to handle any movement of the sprite

It's handy to work with the existing PyGame Sprite layout because a lot of functionality is already provided by the library code.

So let's make a BulletSprite:

```
class BulletSprite( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):

    def __init__( self, bitmap, x, y ):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__( self )
        self.image        = bitmap                 # How the sprite looks
        self.rect         = bitmap.get_rect()      # Bounding box the size of the image
        self.rect.centerx = x                      # position the bullet 
        self.rect.centery = y                      #   about its centre
```

And that's it.  This will give you a stationary sprite, painted as the given bitmap at `(x,y)` on-screen.

So let's now use it:

```
# Create a group of 100 bullets
sprite_image = pygame.image.load( "bullet.png" )
all_bullets  = pygame.sprite.Group()               # Group to hold the sprites
for i in range( 100 ):
    random_x   = 50 + random.randrange( 950 )      # TODO: use proper screen size
    random_y   = 50 + random.randrange( 950 )
    new_sprite = BulletSprite( sprite_image, random_x, random_y )
    all_bullets.add( new_sprite )

# Main Window loop
while True:
    # Handle user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            break

    # Paint the window
    window.fill( ( 0, 0, 0 ) )       # Paint it Black
    all_bullets.update()             # move all the bullets
    all_bullets.draw( window )       # Paint all the bullets

    pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
```

And that's it.  After the sprites are created, it takes two lines of code to move them all, and draw them all.

But they wont move yet.  For them to move, the `BulletSprite` needs to have an `update()` function.  This function does whatever is necessary to move the sprite - apply velocity, gravity, whatever.  The net effect is the sprite's rectangle's (x,y) is changed.

So adding some changes to the sprite - first an `x` and `y` velocity, and then the movement code.

```
class BulletSprite( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):

    def __init__( self, bitmap, x, y ):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__( self )
        self.image        = bitmap                 # How the sprite looks
        self.rect         = bitmap.get_rect()      # Bounding box the size of the image
        self.rect.centerx = x                      # position the bullet 
        self.rect.centery = y                      #   about its centre

        self.x_move = random.randrange( -3, 3 )    # simple random velocity
        self.y_move = random.randrange( -3, 3 )

    def update( self ):
        x = self.rect.centerx + self.x_move        # calculate the new position
        y = self.rect.centerx + self.y_move        # by applying an offset

        # has the sprite gone off-screen
        if ( x < 0 or x > 1000 or y < 0 or y > 1000 )
            self.kill()                            # remove from the group
        else:           
            self.rect.centerx = x                  # RE-position the bullet 
            self.rect.centery = y
```

Every time the `update()` is called on your sprite group (`all_bullets`), the sprite library will go and call the `update()` function on every sprite in the group.  The code checks to see if the bullet is off-screen (I lazily used 1000 as a placeholder for screen width & height), and if-so, the `sprite.kill()` function handles the removing from the group and cleaning up.  It's very easy.